# Char pointers: Creating dynamic string array, assignment and passing to other function and other small dude - C

Tags: c, string, pointers, malloc

I am studying pointers used with dynamic memory and I have done a MCVE code where I create a dynamic string array (pointer to pointer to char), init it with malloc, assign values, send it to a function which prints them and return ok, then free memory (full code is on the botton of the post. I recommend see full code before the question).

Doing that, I have doubts:

- String array should be created like: ?

  ```
  char **stringArray = NULL;
  stringArray = malloc(NUM_OF_ELEMENTS*sizeof(char)); 
  for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_ELEMENTS; i++)
      stringArray[i] = malloc((STRING_LENGTH+1)*sizeof(char));
  /*
      FIRST: Init a double pointer to char
      SECOND: Create number of elements of the array (number of strings)
              When is created the number of elements... is not needed end it with '\0' char, right?
              When malloc is done... is needed mult it *sizeof(char)? In case it is not like that, is needed mult it *sizeof(anything)?
      THIRD: Create length of each string
  */
  ```
- Input (by user, or manually) is correctly done?

  ```
  // Creating elements
  // User input
  for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_ELEMENTS-1; i++) {
      printf("Input: %i with letters (One, Two,..): ", i+1);
      gets(userInput);
      strcpy(stringArray[i], userInput); // stringArray[0] = "One"; stringArray[1] = "Two"
  }
  // Manually
  strcpy(stringArray[NUM_OF_ELEMENTS-1], "Three"); // stringArray[2] = "Three"
  ```
- A function which returns a string should be a pointer to char too, right?

  ```
  char *functionWhichReturnsOneString() {
      return "string";
  }
  ```
- Are correctly passed/receibed parameters by value and by reference?

  ```
  printElementsOfStringArrayPassedByValue(stringArray) // Call to function
  char *printElementsOfStringArrayPassedByValue(char **stringArray) {
      int i = 0;

      for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_ELEMENTS; i++)
          printf("%s\n", stringArray[i]);

      return "OK";
  }

  printElementsOfStringArray2PassedByReference(&stringArray) // Call to function
  char *printElementsOfStringArray2PassedByReference(char ***stringArray) {
      int i = 0;

      for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_ELEMENTS; i++)
          printf("%s\n", (*stringArray)[i]); // Is it equal to: *((*stringArray)+i) ?

      return "OK";
  }
  ```

  - Is equal: `(*stringArray)[i])` and: `*((*stringArray)+i)`, right?

---

Full code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NUM_OF_ELEMENTS 3
#define STRING_LENGTH 35

char *printElementsOfStringArrayPassedByValue(char **stringArray) {
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_ELEMENTS; i++)
        printf("%s\n", stringArray[i]);

    return "OK";
}

char *printElementsOfStringArray2PassedByReference(char ***stringArray) {
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_ELEMENTS; i++)
        printf("%s\n", (*stringArray)[i]); // Is it equal to: *((*stringArray)+i) ?

    return "OK";
}

int main(void) {
    // Variables
    int i = 0;
    char userInput[STRING_LENGTH] = {'\0'};
    char **stringArray = NULL;
    char returnedValue[STRING_LENGTH] = {'\0'};

    // Creating array of strings
    stringArray = malloc(NUM_OF_ELEMENTS*sizeof(char)); // Here is correct: *sizeof(char)?; Is not needed \0 char?

    // Creating each element of the array
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_ELEMENTS; i++)
        stringArray[i] = malloc((STRING_LENGTH+1)*sizeof(char));

    // Creating elements
        // User input
        for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_ELEMENTS-1; i++) {
            printf("Input: %i with letters (One, Two,..): ", i+1);
            gets(userInput);
            strcpy(stringArray[i], userInput); // stringArray[0] = "One"; stringArray[1] = "Two"
        }
        // Manually
        strcpy(stringArray[NUM_OF_ELEMENTS-1], "Three"); // stringArray[2] = "Three"

    strcpy(returnedValue, printElementsOfStringArrayPassedByValue(stringArray)); // Pass by value and return a string
    printf("%s - Ended print 1\n", returnedValue);
    strcpy(returnedValue, printElementsOfStringArray2PassedByReference(&stringArray)); // Pass by reference and return a string
    printf("%s - Ended print 2\n", returnedValue);

    // Freeing memory
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_ELEMENTS; i++) {
        free(stringArray[i]);
        stringArray[i] = NULL;
    }
    free(stringArray);
    stringArray = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: don't use gets()!!!!

Comment: `stringArray = malloc(NUM_OF_ELEMENTS*sizeof(char));` => `stringArray = malloc(NUM_OF_ELEMENTS*sizeof(char *));`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes, you are right. I know use `gets` is unsafe, but was fast method of input for this example, this is the reason of this `gets` :) . And thank you so much for your contribution, I take note of that :)

Comment: Your question contains multiple unrelated questions. It would be better to ask separate questions. But beware of duplicates!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes, I am seeing that this question dont like to comunity due to it have two close votes ( ... I will create separate question instead of it, thank you again :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The method is ok, but the first sizeof argument is wrong (stringArray has the type char**, not char*), better use sizeof with malloc like this:

```
 char **stringArray = NULL;
 stringArray = malloc(NUM_OF_ELEMENTS * sizeof(*stringArray)); 
 for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_ELEMENTS; i++)
     stringArray[i] = malloc((STRING_LENGTH+1) * sizeof(*stringArray[i]));
```

And for masters in programming, better use calloc to handle interger overflow:

```
 char **stringArray = NULL;
 stringArray = calloc(NUM_OF_ELEMENTS, sizeof(*stringArray)); 
 assert(stringArray != NULL);
 for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_ELEMENTS; i++) {
     stringArray[i] = calloc(STRING_LENGTH+1, sizeof(*stringArray[i]));
     assert(stringArray[i] != NULL); 
 }
```

- Yes and do not use `gets`. Erase `gets` from memory. Use `fgets(userInput, sizeof(userInput), stdin);`
- You have to make sure the storage duration for the string is longer then the function. In your example you return a pointer to a [string literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal). And string literals have static storage duration, as if you declared it at file scope, so it's fine here. If you would return a pointer to a [compound literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) or you would initialize the string on stack that would be a problem. Such function will return a pointer to a string, but you don't know if that string exists once the function exits, because the string stops existing after the function returns.
You could also:

```
static char *string_to_return = "string";
char *functionWhichReturnsOneString_global() {
    return string_to_return;
}
char *functionWhichReturnsOneString_static() {
    static char *string_to_return_2 = "string";
    return string_to_return;
}
```

That way string_to_return has a static storage duration and it will be available globally. Other way is to use malloc (or strdup) to allocate memory for a string and return a pointer to that memory (remember to free it afterward(!)):

```
char *functionWhichReturnsOneString_malloc() {
    char *string_to_return = malloc(sizeof("string"));
    memcpy(string_to_return, "string", sizeof("string"));
    return string_to_return;
}
char *functionWhichReturnsOneString_strdup() {
    return strdup("string");
}
```

- The functions do exactly the same. stringArray is an array of pointers to array of characters. It is a pointer, that points to an array of pointers, each of which points to an array of characters. Passing stringArray to a function is enough to modify characters stored in arrays (as stringArray points to these arrays) and to for ex. resize these arrays. If you pass &stringArray, your function may change the number of arrays (ie. NUM_OF_ELEMENTS)(not the number of characters in a particular array, but the number of arrays themselfs). You could do `*stringArray = realloc(*stringArray, (NUM_OF_ELEMENTS+20)*sizeof(**stringArray));`
- Yes. The expression `A[B]` is equal to `B[A]` is equal to `*(B+A)`. Funny, this is also equal to: `*i[*stringArray]`, but this form hurts my eyes.

Comment: OK! Thank you for your help. What is the difference between: `stringArray = malloc(NUM_OF_ELEMENTS*sizeof(*stringArray));` and `stringArray = malloc(NUM_OF_ELEMENTS*sizeof(char *));`. Also: What should I use if I wanna access a concrete position? I mean, I wanna access to STRING_1; CHAR_3? I have tryed `*(*(arr + i) + j)` (being i = 3 -CHAR_3- and j = 1 -STRING_1-) but is not working, any idea? Thank you, again.

Comment: I have tryed also i = STRING_! and j = CHAR_3 and foes not work too (I am trying it inside `printElementsOfStringArray2PassedByReference`)

Comment: If you want string_1: char_3, just do arr[0][2] (remember numbering is from 0). If arr is of type `char**`, it is a pointer to `char*`. `arr[0]` will give you the first `char*` pointer in the array. `arr[0][2]` will give the third char of the first string.

Comment: sizeof operator "queries size of the object or type". Each object has a type and `sizeof(object)` will give the same value as `sizeof(type_of_that_object)`. `*stringArray` or `stringArray[0]` has the type `char*`, so `sizeof(*stringArray)` is equal to `sizeof(char *)`. I prefer to write `sizeof(variable)` for readability and safety, so in case i change the variable declaration (thus change the type of the variable) i don't need to go through all the *allocs and mem* and other functions in the code to change all the sizeof arguments.

Comment: In your expression you switched `i` and `j`, first index is string, then character index in that string. Numbering is from 0, so `j=0` and `i=2` and you want `arr[j][i]`  = `(*(arr+j)[i]` = `*(*(arr+j)+i)` and btw. this is also equal to `*(char*)(((uintptr_t)arr+j*sizeof(*arr))+i*sizeof(**arr))`. If your still interested in this topic, you could read about pointers arithmetic in C. And, no problem, that's a fun topic.